# Authenticate Google access token with ASP.NET Core backend server

Tags: asp.net-core, google-signin, google-api-dotnet-client, google-plus-signin, google-oauth-.net-client

I have Angular2 on client and ASP.NET Core on server side. I use [JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) (aspnetcore-spa template).
For authentication I use [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict) and I follow example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257981/exchanging-a-google-idtoken-for-local-openid-token-c-sharp/40260960).

Now I am on the server side in Controller class method and I would like to validate id_token because this is suggested on [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people) side:

> Important: Do not use the Google IDs returned by getId() or the user's
>   profile information to communicate the currently signed in user to
>   your backend server. Instead, send ID tokens, which can be securely
>   validated on the server.

And I would also like to register user (save email, profile ...) in my database through ASP.NET Core identity.

I would like to use [Google API client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) **to get user information** and store refresh_token. Years ago I manage to do it with PHP, but I can't figure it out with .NET.
I download nuget packages: Google.Apis, Google.Apis.OAuth2.v2, Google.Apis.Plus.v1.

I am not sure which nuget package I need for this, which class should I use, how to set Google ServerKey and how to get user information from information which I get from [gapi.signin2 button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

**In simple:**
How can I validate id_token from .NET with Google .NET Client library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://gusclass.com/blog/2014/07/29/using-google-apis-from-console-apps-in-net/). It is old, but it works.

```
var googleInitializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
googleInitializer.ApiKey = this.config["Authentication:Google:ServerKey"];
Oauth2Service ser = new Oauth2Service(googleInitializer);
Oauth2Service.TokeninfoRequest req = ser.Tokeninfo();
req.AccessToken = request.AccessToken;  //access token received from Google SignIn button
Tokeninfo userinfo = await req.ExecuteAsync();
```

I didn't figure it out how to get Display name and picture on server. But it can be done on client:

```
onGoogleLoginSuccess(user: gapi.auth2.GoogleUser)
{
    console.log("basic profile", user.getBasicProfile());
}
```

**If someone knows more updated solution or how to retrieve basic user profile on server, please share it.**

In addition I can use Google+, but careful because Google Account is not Google+ Account. I didn't have + account and get error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not Found [404] Errors [
>     Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]

in code:

```
var plusService = new PlusService(googleInitializer);
Person me = await plusService.People.Get(userinfo.UserId).ExecuteAsync();
```

but it is possible to get all user information (picture, display name, first name, last name, birthday ...)